# pipe closed without call close

Tags: java, pipe, nio, ice

The pipe is opened by `nio`. I found the write endpoint closed but the read endpoint opened. I checked my code, two endpoint always be closed together. So, is there a possibility that the pipe be closed without call `close` function by myself?

ps. The code is the source code of `zero ice`. I found the problem in the production environment. The code path is `IceInternal.Selector`, the pipe is `_fdIntrRead` and `_fdIntrWrite`. My `ice` version is `3.3.1`.

I got the answer. `NIO` will close channel when the current thread is interrupted. It is a bug of `ice` which was fixed in version `3.6`.

Comment: Most likely you did close it somewhere. I suggest recording where you close a pipe as a log message for now.

Comment: @PeterLawrey. The variable is private. So it must be closed in the single file.

Comment: Are you using try-with-resouces? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html  That could explain why it is closing automatically.

Comment: If it was due to an interrupt you would have got a `ClosedByInterruptException`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did close it somewhere. I am often convinced I haven't closed a resource in cases like this but after diagnosing the problem it turns out I have.

I suggest recording where (including a stack trace) you close a pipe as a log message for now. e.g.

```
new Throwable(pipe + " closed here").printStackTrace();
pipe.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a possibility that the pipe be closed without call close function by myself?

NIO doesn't close things, unless you got a `ClosedByInterruptException`. Only the application can do that.

Comment: Its possible that AutoCloseable could be coming into play.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Comment: @JohnnyV Of course, but that is the application doing that, not NIO.